# Model fit becomes better after adding a fixed effect

Tags: mixed-model

I fit the following model to the repeated measures data:

$$Y \sim A + (B|id) + (C|id)$$

However, if I add a fixed effect of B in the model:

$$Y \sim A + B + (B|id) + (C|id)$$

quality of the fit increases ($AIC$, $R^2$, predictive power, etc.)

Why is it happening since I already have random effects of B in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that random effects are constrained such that the sum of the random effects = 0. In other words, random effects are the cluster's deviation from the fixed effect.

So in your case, the fixed effect of B is likely different than 0, but when you exclude this fixed effect from the model, you are still forcing the average of all the $B|id$ to be 0.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. Similarily, when I add the fixed effect of C, the model does not become better, and the fixed effect of C is not significant and close to 0.